How can I add retry behavior to the Laravel Redis client?
I'm using Laravel with phpredis and sometimes I get transient errors of the form SSL: Connection reset by peer. I'd like to configure Laravel to retry the command when this happens.
The current means I see to do this is:

Use Redis::extend() to replace the 'phpredis' driver with my own custom instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Redis\Connector.
In my connector, create a connection which proxies all calls to an underlying PhpRedisConnection instance using __call, wrapping the calls with retry logic.

The feels clumsy; is there a simpler way to get command-level retry behavior?

If by "command-level" retry behavior you mean on the individual calls in your code, you might consider the retry() helper.
$foo = retry(5, function () {
    return Cache::get('foo');
}, 100);

This will retry up to 5 times, with 100ms between attempts.

(That said, Redis has always been rock-solid for me. I'd be digging into why you're getting connection resets frequently enough to notice.)

we're seeing these connection resets transiently/occasionally with AWS Elasticache (serverless). If you have a similar setup and don't ever see these issues, that would be interesting to know!

If it's very occasional and brief, it might be the cache cluster scaling.
